# Magento: Can't retrieve entity config: sales/sales_flat_order

Tags: magento, runtime-error

Magento is presenting the following error report when attempting to view the Sales -> Orders page on the administration back end.

I have attempted to regenerate the cache's and enabled/disabled the compiler, both with no success in clearing the error.

Other points to note include the installation of a new OPC module today as well as a manual restart of mySQL.

```
Magento Commerce
There has been an error processing your request

Can't retrieve entity config: sales/sales_flat_order

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(272): Mage::throwException('Can't retrieve ...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(284): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getTableName('sales/sales_fla...')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(488): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getTable('sales_flat_orde...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(569): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getTable('sales_flat_orde...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php(60): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->join('sales_flat_orde...', 'main_table.enti...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#10 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#13 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#14 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#22 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#23 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#24 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#25 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#32 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /var/www/vhosts/xxxxx.com/httpdocs/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}

Error log record number: 830015795490
Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright © 2012 Magento Inc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by an erroneous file located in the following location:

```
app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

Removing or renaming the file had no effect until the Magento compiler was disabled or recompiled. To disable the compiler, from the administration panel select System -> Tools -> Compilation. Choose either disable, to disable the compiler entirely, or 'Run Compilation Process', to update all compiled files.

Once removed and compiler updated, the Sales -> Orders grid view loaded successfully with no issues.